# Angular 7 + ag-Grid show incorrect warning in the console

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I am using Angular 7 and ag-Grid Community edition v19.x and use "sortable" attribute in my column def

```
 this.columnDefs =  [
    {headerName: 'First Name ', field: 'firstName', sortable: true, filter: true },
    {headerName: 'Last Name', field: 'lastName', sortable: true, filter: true },
    {headerName: 'DOB', width: 150, field: 'dob', sortable: false, filter: false},        
    {headerName: 'Document', width: 400, field: 'documentName', sortable: true, filter: true},
    {headerName: 'Reference', field: 'reference'}
  ];
```

However, when I run the app , the console shows the following warning

```
ag-grid: invalid colDef property 'sortable' did you mean any of these:
```

Comment: Update ag-Grid to a newer version.

Comment: I did,     "ag-grid-angular": "^19.1.2",
    "^ag-grid-community": "^19.1.3",

Comment: `sortable` property came out in v20

Comment: Perfect. It works now.Thank you.

Comment: That is something I don't like about ag-grid, you don't know which feature is supported for a given version from their documentation.

Comment: Agreed. Documentation should be clear enough.

Comment: @ABOS: That's not really true. The current documentation is always for the most recent version. They have a "Documentation Archive" if you're on an older version: https://www.ag-grid.com/archive/. It is a bit hard to find though, and there are some other downsides.

Comment: nope, if you search inside an old version and it still pulls results for current version of document...

Comment: @ABOS, I think thirtydot is correct. When I search under 19.1,2 I don't see the property sortable. https://www.ag-grid.com/archive/19.1.2/javascript-grid-column-properties/

Comment: @jprism, try to use the search input on top left, normally I just search .... for example, type `sortable` and check it out

Comment: @ABOS: You're right, the search is broken. The old documentation is still correct though.

Comment: @thirtydot  :)   :)